# How to handle security constraint in Google App Engine Flexible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-flexible

We are moving from GAE Standard to Flex, during that I had security constraints specified in my web.xml earlier (on standard) which was redirecting user to login page if user is not admin or not logged in.

this is how I had specified it in web.xml, which is working fine in standard gae

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>push-handlers</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/push-handlers/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>           
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But now when I moved to flex that setting is not working and it is not allowing any traffic to pass in...

If I specify that setting in app.yaml still it doesn't works...this is what I am specifying in app.yaml

`handlers:
 - url: /_ah/push-handlers/*
   script: unused
   login: admin`

Can someone help me in how to handle this in flex?

Answer (score 1):

The "login: admin" handler is not available in App Engine Flex. You can see the upgrading docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#appyaml_changes).

[This doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#users) provides alternative to the "Users" service which made the login handler possible in GAE standard.